# how to make deb package version 2?

Tags: dpkg, deb

I am trying to build deb packages using deb version 2, I downloaded `apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb` when I extracted it I found 3 files inside it.

1) control.tar.gz
2) data.tar.xz
3) debian-binary

I know, how to make older version.

but didn't find a correct guide to make deb in format 2

please provide video tutorial or article link!

Comment: did you find any?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo, yes found it, check answer

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution

1) Decide on the name of your package. Standard debian notation is all lowercase in the following format:

```
Code: <project>_<major version>.<minor version>-<package revision>
```

2) For example, you could name your first package...
Code: mypackage_1.0-1

3) copy all all your program files to mypackage_1.0-1

4) create DEBIAN directory inside mypackage_1.0-1

5) create control file inside DEBIAN with below content (modify it as your package)

```
Package: mypackage
Version: 1.0-1
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: i386
Depends: libsomethingorrather (>= 1.2.13), anotherDependency (>= 1.2.6)
Maintainer: Your Name <you@email.com>
Description: my Package
 When you need some sunshine, just run this
 small program!
 (the space before each line in the description is important)
```

7) Now you just need to make the package:

Code: dpkg-deb --build mypackage_1.0-1

Comment: Thanks. I will try this one. Meanwhile am tinkling around debreate!

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo if possible please post solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950317/jquery-ui-div-not-draggable-on-dropped